# why does azure service bus subscription report active messages but onmessage retrieves nothing

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have an azure service bus topic/subscription.  When I query the subscription, I am informed there are 11,646 active messages.

However, the message loop (as implemented with subscription.onMessage) retrieves nothing.

If I submit a message, the count will go up by one, I receive it from the loop and when I .complete the message, the count goes down by one.

And before you jump to 'deadletter', there is nothing in the deadletter queue.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check to see the messages in the queue don't have an existing Lock on them?

Comment: how do you check this?

Comment: The brokered message object has a LockedUntilUtc property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.lockeduntilutc.aspx
You could check that to see if there is a lock on the message. 

I'd suggest downloading Service bus explorer to help see all the properties on the messages in the queue https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer

Comment: the service bus explorer tells me there are 11, 646 messages but when I click on 'messages', no messages are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an ACL issue.  We have the same issue when working with the Service Bus Explorer.